# How to perform Group penalty for feature selection in multi-class classification?

Tags: classification, optimization, linear-model, lasso

I want to do multi-class classification, XW=Y, where $X\in R^{n\times p}$, $W\in R^{p\times c}$, $Y\in R^{n\times c}$, in which Y is of one-hot, and n, p, c stands for numbers of samples, features, classes, respectively.

Before classification, I want to do feature selection to delete some redundant features. Suppose I know that every 3 consecutive rows of X (features, without overlapping) are closely connected, therefore, to do that, adding group lasso penalty **(is this group lasso?**) is what I need:

$min\ ||XW-Y||_2^2+\sum_{block={\{1,2,3\}}}^{\{p//3-2,p//3-1,p//3\}}\lambda_r||W_{block,\cdot}||_2$,

i.e., every 3 row of W is set to a group for regularization, as illustrated below.

(Although a cross-entropy term would be better,  I use $||XW-Y||_2^2$ for ease of representation, and in fact sklearn does classification in the same way.)

[image]

My questions are:

1. Is it OK to take every 3 rows of W as a group? I have browsed several **group lasso** papers, but they usually do regression, and it is elements in the column, w, that are grouped together, instead of rows in the matrix W. And some $l_{2,1}$ paper only regularizes single rows of W.
2. If it is OK, are there appropriate algorithms for solving the problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you take "each row" as a group, how is that a grouping? I doubt that "group lasso" is what you need here (what is usually denoted by this term is something else - the "group" in "group lasso" does not refer to classification - as you apparently already have realised), but even without that $XW\approx Y$ may not be the best approach, as this doesn't take into account the categorical nature of the $Y$. You may want to read about multinomial logistic regression, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Multinomial_logistic_regression:_Many_explanatory_variables_and_many_categories

Comment: @ChristianHennig Thank you for your reply! If "group lasso" is not suitable, is there any tool to jointly regularize a row of W?

Comment: After changing the question, it looks like you actually have groups of features, so group lasso may apply. And actually it may be applied in the standard way, as in regression groups of features refer to the columns of $X$ as in your setting, not to the columns of $W$ (unless you consider regression with multivariate outcomes, the $W$, usually denoted $\beta$ in regression, is not a matrix, just a vector).

Comment: Note by the way that the effect of group lasso is that all members of a group are either jointly selected or jointly dropped. Make sure this is what you want. Sometimes if a group of variables are closely related, it makes sense to have just one of them in the model.

Comment: The group lasso as explained here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)#Group_lasso has just a single $\lambda$, not $\lambda_r$. I doubt that this corresponds to what you have written down, although I'm not sure.